# Test locally an Azure Function with connection to a database based on Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm creating an `Azure Function` that has to connect to a database in a virtual machine on Azure with Microsoft SQL installed. The authentication is based on Azure Active Directory.

For this reason, I created this `SqlConnectionFactory` using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory
{
    public static SqlConnectionFactory TeamDbConnectionFactory { get; } = 
        new SqlConnectionFactory("myserver", "mydatabase", 60);

    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlConnectionFactory(string dbServer, string dbName, int commandTimeout)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new()
        {
            DataSource = dbServer,
            InitialCatalog = dbName,
            Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryDefault,
            CommandTimeout = commandTimeout
        };

        _connectionString = builder.ToString();
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateAndOpenConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

When I call this function, it fails when I open the connection because

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user ''.'

[image]

I login in the machine with the right account. From the machine I can connect to the database with SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

That auth option tries a number of different places to find credentials.  On your Azure Function it uses Managed Identity.  Locally you have to enable one of the others:

[image]

[Using Active Directory Default Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication)